# Custom UIView not visible on addSubview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uikit

I have created a simple ProgressView class that I want to be shown when I'm doing some long tasks.  However when I add it to the parent view it never becomes visible and layoutSubviews is never called.

The class is implemented as follows:

```
@implementation ProgressView

@synthesize title;
@synthesize cancel;
@synthesize progress;
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    //frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 240, 112 );
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if ( self )
    {
        self.title      = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.cancel     = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.progress   = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];

        self.backgroundColor    = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

        [self addSubview: self.title];
        [self addSubview: self.cancel];
        [self addSubview: self.progress];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id) createWithTitle: (NSString*) pTitle
{
    ProgressView* pRet  = [[ProgressView alloc] initWithTitle: pTitle];
    return pRet;
}

- (id) initWithTitle: (NSString*) pTitle
{
    self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 240, 112 )];
    if ( self )
    {
        self.title.text = pTitle;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    CGSize superFrameSize       = self.superview.frame.size;
    CGSize halfSuperFrameSize   = CGSizeMake( superFrameSize.width / 2, superFrameSize.height / 2 );

    CGSize frameSize            = self.frame.size;
    CGSize halfFrameSize        = CGSizeMake( frameSize.width / 2, frameSize.height / 2 );

    // Center the window on its parent.
    [self setFrame: CGRectMake( halfSuperFrameSize.width - halfFrameSize.width, halfSuperFrameSize.height - halfFrameSize.height, frameSize.width, frameSize.height )];

    [self.title     setFrame: CGRectMake( 4,  4, frameSize.width - 8, 24 )];
    [self.progress  setFrame: CGRectMake( 4, 32, frameSize.width - 8, 24 )];
    [self.cancel    setFrame: CGRectMake( 4, 64, frameSize.width - 8, 44 )];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And I add the view as follow:

```
pProgressView   = [[ProgressView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Downloading..."];
[pProgressView setDelegate: self];
[self.view addSubview: pProgressView];
```

But it never displays.  I've checked the remove is definitely happening later and there is plenty of time for the view to become visible.  I'm at a loss however.  Whatever I do the ProgressView just won't display.

Can someone point out the, most probably stupid, mistake I'm making?

Comment: where do you add your view ? The problem could come from here

Comment: @NicolasBonnet: Thanks Nicolas but I don't think I'm doing it anywhere odd.  I'm doing from inside a delegate call, which I've confirmed is occurring on the main thread.

Comment: I've also confirmed that a few seconds later, when the download completes, pProgressView.superview is the same s "self.view" ...

Comment: Isn't it possible that your main thread is blocked right after you add this view, and that is why it doesn't appear? I'm assuming that you are doing something right after adding `pProgressView`. Try to move that "something" to a secondary thread.

Comment: @Levi: Nope ... because the UIListView the view should be appearing over it still responsive ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it, and I'm REALLY stupid.

I am using a navigation controller.  And the NavigtionViewController handles the download initiation. Only problem is that its being generated by  a child view controller.  So I'm adding my ProgressView to a view that is currently not visible ...

D'OH!

Sorry all.

My new addSubview code is as follows:

```
[self.navigationController.topViewController.view addSubview: pProgressView];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the designated initializer in -initWithTitle, not [super init]:

```
self = [self initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 240, 112 )];
```

The designated initializer is the one which calls the superclass' initializer, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html) for more info.

Comment: Just to clarify this is in your `initWithTitle`

Comment: @Goz - have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see the labels etc being created properly?

Comment: Are you using constraints?

Comment: @ff10: How do I tell if I am?

Comment: @Goz try calling [super layoutSubviews] in your -layoutSubviews method.

Comment: @ff10: Given its never called I doubt very much it will make any difference ... but you are right ... it probably ought to be there!

Comment: @ff10: and it did make no difference :(

Comment: Then I do believe the error lies somewhere else, not in the code you posted.

Comment: @ff10: And it does I've just tracked it down ... how embarassing :D